# Xcode 7 crashes while it is creating new file

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

I have "El Capitan GM" and I've updated my Xcode to Xcode 7 GM. Now I can't create new classes, Xcode crashes with message:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSOpenPanel setAccessoryViewDisclosed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f940cf89af0
```

Is someone had faced with this problem? Is someone had solved it?

**UPD**

Now I'm using AppCode to create new files and Xcode to write a code.

Comment: not with 7GM on Yosemite, there is also a 7.1 beta you could try

Comment: I'm downloading a 7.1 version. But it is very strange bug for me.

Comment: I am facing same issue on El Capitan GM. Now using older version.

Comment: older version of Xcode*

Comment: It is very sadly bug, because XCode 7.1 have same bug. I do not think what is regular problem (problem that reproduces on all computers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also happened to me.

I updated my system to El Capitan GM (previously, I updated from Yosemite to El Capitan Beta versions),

updated Xcode from 6.5 to 7.0.

When I create any kind of project, It keeps crashing when I click 'Next' button after filling project name, etc.

I tried to clean preferences, tried to delete Xcode 7.0 and reinstall it.
None of these solutions work.

My solution is:

Restart my My Macbook Air, and enter Recovery Mode,

and choose Reinstall Mac OS X.

Wish this helps you.